# Update query failing with transaction enabled sqlite3+android+cocos2dx

Tags: android, sqlite, transactions, sql-update, cocos2d-x

We have been working on an android app which uses cocos2dx. We use sqlite3 for storing data locally on the device. 
We use c++ code to connect and use the database. Recently we used transactions, it runs fine on iOS platform 
(cocos2dx apps are cross platform) but it fails on android.

This is weird because only update queries in the transaction fail and that too if you run multiple updates in a loop. 
Every other query (insert, delete, select) runs fine in loop. We are not using multiple threads, so whatever runs, runs 
on the main thread neither we are opening multiple connections to the database. The same code works if you turn off 
the transaction. We don't want to give up transactions. One solution is to use "insert or replace" query instead of update 
which is insert or insert-delete but I am not sure what will happen if the table is having foreign key relationship. We can 
drop the foreign key constraint if we assume the data is proper.

For each query we prepare a statement, step through it and then finalize it so every statement is finalized even if the query
fails. For pragma setting and begin and end transaction we are using sqlite_exec which wraps the above process.

Here is a test log:-

```
09-03 19:36:35.175: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON 
09-03 19:36:35.175: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): begin transaction 
09-03 19:36:35.180: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.185: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): enter loop 
09-03 19:36:35.185: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): update TestTable set ID_Type = 2 where Test_ID = 133 
09-03 19:36:35.185: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.185: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): insert into TestTable(Test_ID) values(1) 
09-03 19:36:35.185: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.185: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): delete from TestTable where Test_ID = 1 
09-03 19:36:35.185: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.190: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.190: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): update TestTable set ID_Type = 2 where Test_ID = 135 
09-03 19:36:35.195: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Error 14 update TestTable set ID_Type = 2 where Test_ID = 135 
09-03 19:36:35.195: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): insert into TestTable(Test_ID) values(1) 
09-03 19:36:35.195: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.195: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): delete from TestTable where Test_ID = 1 
09-03 19:36:35.195: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.195: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.195: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): update TestTable set ID_Type = 1 where Test_ID = 140 
09-03 19:36:35.195: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Error 14 update TestTable set ID_Type = 1 where Test_ID = 140 
09-03 19:36:35.200: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): insert into TestTable(Test_ID) values(1) 
09-03 19:36:35.200: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.200: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): delete from TestTable where Test_ID = 1 
09-03 19:36:35.200: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.200: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.200: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): update TestTable set ID_Type = 1 where Test_ID = 141 
09-03 19:36:35.200: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Error 14 update TestTable set ID_Type = 1 where Test_ID = 141 
09-03 19:36:35.205: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): insert into TestTable(Test_ID) values(1) 
09-03 19:36:35.205: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.205: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): delete from TestTable where Test_ID = 1 
09-03 19:36:35.205: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.205: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.205: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): update TestTable set ID_Type = 1 where Test_ID = 142 
09-03 19:36:35.205: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Error 14 update TestTable set ID_Type = 1 where Test_ID = 142 
09-03 19:36:35.215: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): insert into TestTable(Test_ID) values(1) 
09-03 19:36:35.215: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.215: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): delete from TestTable where Test_ID = 1 
09-03 19:36:35.215: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.215: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.215: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): update TestTable set ID_Type = 0 where Test_ID = 144 
09-03 19:36:35.215: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Error 14 update TestTable set ID_Type = 0 where Test_ID = 144 
09-03 19:36:35.220: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): insert into TestTable(Test_ID) values(1) 
09-03 19:36:35.220: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.220: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): delete from TestTable where Test_ID = 1 
09-03 19:36:35.220: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.220: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.220: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): update TestTable set ID_Type = 0 where Test_ID = 146 
09-03 19:36:35.220: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Error 14 update TestTable set ID_Type = 0 where Test_ID = 146 
09-03 19:36:35.225: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): insert into TestTable(Test_ID) values(1) 
09-03 19:36:35.225: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.225: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): delete from TestTable where Test_ID = 1 
09-03 19:36:35.225: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.225: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.225: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): update TestTable set ID_Type = 1 where Test_ID = 158 
09-03 19:36:35.230: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Error 14 update TestTable set ID_Type = 1 where Test_ID = 158 
09-03 19:36:35.230: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): insert into TestTable(Test_ID) values(1) 
09-03 19:36:35.230: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.230: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): delete from TestTable where Test_ID = 1 
09-03 19:36:35.230: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): Executed 
09-03 19:36:35.230: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): select Test_ID, ID_Type from TestTable 
09-03 19:36:35.235: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): exit loop 
09-03 19:36:35.235: D/cocos2d-x debug info(30445): rollback
```

The above log indicates where it enters the loop and where it exits the loop. Inside loop we perform update, insert, delete and select in the same order. 
You can create any table and check this. I have no idea what is going wrong. We have checked following things:-

1. No multiple thread accessing.
2. No multiple connections at the same time.
3. The database and database_journal (temporary database for transaction) has read write permission otherwise even insert and delete will fail.
4. We tried begin immediate transaction
5. We tried switching off the Synchronization pragma
6. We tested on different android devices (samsung and micromax)

If you drop the transaction the same code works fine.

> Edit

You can try this on android, update query fails. If you just remove the transaction, it will work fine. You can try insert, delete or select all these work fine. Typically update execute maximum once and then sqlite error 14 "unable to open database" comes.

Code Here:

```
sqlite3 *pSqliteConn = NULL;
    if (sqlite3_open(PATH_OF_DB.c_str(), &pSqliteConn) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        bool success = true;

        char *pErrorMsg = NULL;
        int code = sqlite3_exec(pSqliteConn, "begin transaction", NULL, NULL, &pErrorMsg);
        if (pErrorMsg)
        {
            success = false;
            CCLog("Error %d %s", code, pErrorMsg);
            sqlite3_free(pErrorMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            CCLog("begin transaction");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            pErrorMsg = NULL;
            code = sqlite3_exec(pSqliteConn, "update Test_Table set ID_Type = 2 where Test_ID = 144", NULL, NULL, &pErrorMsg);
            if (pErrorMsg)
            {
                success = false;
                CCLog("Error %d %s", code, pErrorMsg);
                sqlite3_free(pErrorMsg);
            }
            else
            {
                CCLog("Executed");
            }
        }

        if (success)
        {
            pErrorMsg = NULL;
            code = sqlite3_exec(pSqliteConn, "commit", NULL, NULL, &pErrorMsg);

            if (pErrorMsg)
            {
                CCLog("Error %d %s", code, pErrorMsg);
                sqlite3_free(pErrorMsg);
            }
            else
            {
                CCLog("commit");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pErrorMsg = NULL;
            code = sqlite3_exec(pSqliteConn, "rollback", NULL, NULL, &pErrorMsg);

            if (pErrorMsg)
            {
                CCLog("Error %d %s", code, pErrorMsg);
                sqlite3_free(pErrorMsg);
            }
            else
            {
                CCLog("rollback");
            }
        }

        sqlite3_close(pSqliteConn);
    }
    else
    {
        CCLog("connection failed");
    }
```

Log of above code in Android:

```
09-09 17:25:58.384: D/cocos2d-x debug info(12087): begin transaction
09-09 17:25:58.387: D/cocos2d-x debug info(12087): Executed
09-09 17:25:58.387: D/cocos2d-x debug info(12087): Error 14 unable to open database file
09-09 17:25:58.387: D/cocos2d-x debug info(12087): Error 14 unable to open database file
09-09 17:25:58.388: D/cocos2d-x debug info(12087): Error 14 unable to open database file
09-09 17:25:58.388: D/cocos2d-x debug info(12087): Error 14 unable to open database file
09-09 17:25:58.389: D/cocos2d-x debug info(12087): rollback
```

Comment: There is a bug in your code. Which you decided to keep a secret.

Comment: I din't get you.. You need more info ? Do I have to post code ?

Comment: No, you don't have to post the code that tries to update the DB. But then nobody will be able to help to.

Comment: @CL. I have added a snippet which is failing on android for me.

Comment: This is not the code that generated the log.

Comment: @CL. The generated log uses a wrapper class over sqlite connection and it is some where in the app for updating local db. The code above is the  general scenario where we are getting the problem. Even this simple case fails, so do you have any suggestion for this ?

Comment: Then show the log of this simple case.

Comment: @CL. Added Log of simple case. Here first update executed and rest failed. Even if you modify different rows it will fail

Comment: I am getting same error. Any solution @AlokRao ??

Answer (score 0):

The message "unable to open database file" on the first modifying SQL statement in a transaction indicates that SQLite was not able to create the rollback journal file.

Ensure that you have write access to the database directory.

Comment: If it is the problem of 'write access' then first update query should also fail.